# Loop over column of file in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line of more than 70.000 lines and 11 columns. The 4th column is a position. I want to count each line that has a position that is 100 higher than the position in the above line and a 100 lower than the position in the below line.

I would like to do this without importing the data to R, so I can put into my shell script. I am however not that experienced in shell.

Example of data:

```
x    y    z    1
x    y    z    80
x    y    z    200
x    y    z    310
x    y    z    390
x    y    z    500
x    y    z    830
```

I want to count the 3rd and the 6th rows as their value in the 4th column is fulfilling my requirements, so my output here should be "2".

I have tried to search for information on how to do this but have been stuck for some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'srec && NR==srec+1 && $4>sv+100{count++; sv=srec=0}
     frec && NR==frec+1 && $4>fv+100{fv=frec=0; sv=$4; srec=NR}
     {fv=$4; frec=NR}
     END{print count}' file

2
```

Comment: The results produced from your code differs from the results produced from karakfa's code. How does the code differ?

Comment: I am trying to verify the correctness of both commands. Can you provide bigger sample data on a pastebin.com to help this testing.

Comment: I have not tried pastebin.com before, so I had to figure it out + extracting the data from the server I work on. It's here: http://pastebin.com/9mFDKwm4

Comment: It says it is a private paste. You need to make it public

Comment: It should be public now :)

Comment: ok I have verified further and it seems my update code is producing more accurate results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your code finds one less than karakfa's code now. Could that be the initial one?

Comment: More that count it is actually accuracy. [I have created a small demo to show case this difference](http://ideone.com/OWeS0W)

Answer (score 3):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk '$4>p+100 && p>pp+100{c++} {pp=p;p=$4} END{print c}' file
2
```

**Explanation**

- `$4>p+100 && p>pp+100{c++}`  if field 4 is greater than prev+100 AND prev is greater than prev prev + 100 increment the counter (started with zero initial value)
- `{pp=p;p=$4}` set the new prev prev and prev
- `END{print c}` when all rows are done print the counter.

Comment: may need special handling for the first two rows.  It will assume zero for missing values.

Comment: That is no problem, since I actually would like counts for positions that has a a "neightbour" within 100 to each side, and my position data starts far from 100. 
Would you care to elaborate slightly on what the arguments used with awk does?
I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Test with `awk '$4>p+100 && p>pp+100{c++} {pp=p;p=$4} END{print c}' <<< $'1 2 3 110\n1 2 3 310'` It will give `1` even if there are only 2 records in input.